# Correct Clock to improve Accuracy in Java

Tags: java, performance, time

I'd like to create MIDI clock which works basically like a normal clock. It simply ticks and counts its ticks. Now I have read quite a few times that `Thread.sleep()` isn't accurate at all. So correcting it every every few cycles ensures that it is stable in the long term?

**My Clock Class**

```
public class Clock implements Runnable {

   long beatsPassed = 0; 
   double bpm = 120;       // default
   double beatLength;   // default
   boolean running = false;

   Clock(int bpm) {
       this.bpm = bpm;
       this.beatLength = 60.0 / bpm;
       this.running = true;
   }

   public void run() {

       int beatLengthInMS = (int) (this.beatLength * 1000);
       long baseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
       // long corrected = 1;

       try {

           while (running) {

               // check delay every 9 beats
               // mod == 0 lets it the first time through which causes a negative timeout
               if (this.beatsPassed % 10 == 9) {
                   // corrected = (System.currentTimeMillis() - baseTime) - (beatLengthInMS * 9);
                   Thread.sleep(beatLengthInMS + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - baseTime) - (beatLengthInMS * 9)));
                   baseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

               } else {
                   Thread.sleep(beatLengthInMS);
               }

               this.beatsPassed++;
               // System.out.println(corrected);
           }

       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

Now I have measured actually quite steady times. It always adds about 6-9ms.
Am I forgetting something fundamental or is my approach wrong? Also great would be if you could tell me a more performant way to this?

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: If you're trying to produce a reliable clock based on `sleep()` then you're attacking the problem from the wrong direction. Use `sleep()`, but on each tick measure the time elapsed from your start time and update your clock according to the time passed.

Comment: My question is in the end of the post. If my approach is wrong or if there's a better? Because my results are contrary to what my research on this topic suggests.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach (apart from using Timer, there are AFAIK two of them in the JDK) is a method

```
void sleepUntil(long absoluteTime) throw InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (now >= absoluteTime) break;
        Thread.sleep(absoluteTime - now);
    }
}
```

The loop is used because of spurious wakeups (which may never occur in practice, but better safe than sorry). The `absoluteTime` gets computed in advance (basically, you only look at the current time at the very beginning).

Comment: This won't prevent `sleep` from sleeping *too long*. For something like `sleep(1)`, one has to assume that it may sleep 5ms or even 10ms... (I don't have a solution either, except for some busy waiting with `System.nanotime()` ... millisecond-precise timing is hard to achieve in Java...)

Comment: @Marco13 if your computer is cpu bound and nothing is moving, then is some cases you may never be able to get the precision you want.  Better just to print the time now.

Comment: @Marco13 AFAIK, there's nothing what could help in this direction. AFAIK assuming that 1. a core is free, 2. the time resolution is sufficient, 3. the system is not overloaded otherwise, it doesn't take longer. The `nanotime` busy waiting is a good idea.